# Blazor site returning empty html page for any url when deployed to IIS

Tags: iis, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I have created a site using blazor in .net 6 core and have deployed this site to 3 different servers without any major hiccups.
When deploying to a 4th server I am getting a strange issue where my site is just returning an html page with an empty head and empty body.
Another strange part of this is that it doesnt matter what url i enter into the browser it returns this blank page. For example applicationName/index.html is supposed to be the login page, but it returns the empty page, but i can even put applicationName/garbage (a page that doesnt exist) and it will also return an empty page.
There are no IIS errors being logged, no errors in the console of the browser, and there are no errors in the event viewer.

This site has worked fine at 3 other servers, I have .net 6.0.22 hosting bundle installed on the server.

I have tried reparing the .net 6 hosting bundle, installed the .net 6 desktop runtime, and verified iis configuration settings are the same as the other servers.

I am expecting to get either an error page when navigating to a page that doesnt exist in my application, or for my blazor application to return the expected pages when navigating to a valid url.

Comment: Drake, while this may seem harsh, this is a pure deployment issue.  You have already proved with 3 deployments that there's nothing wrong with the code.  SO is about coding problems: Deployment is not on-topic - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  Look at your question.  Be realistic: can anyone realistically give you an answer based on the information you've provided?  Your question will be downgraded and probably closed for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple websites hosted on this server, then you can check if the other websites are working properly. When you encounter a blank page, I suggest you try going into the application pool and restart it or recycle it.

For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, the best way is to use failed request tracking, it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.
This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: [Troubleshoot failed requests using tracing in IIS](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

In addition, this video explains in detail [how to solve the problem that the IIS website only displays a blank page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmuJBQFFVGw). I hope it will be helpful to you.